# Energy loss of a bouncing ball

Tags: energy

I am trying to model, with computer graphics, a bouncing ball.  There is a wikipedia entry for this.  It states that the energy loss from the impact is given by the following equation:

$$\text{Energy Loss} = \frac{K_i - K_f}{K_i}  \times  100 \;\% = (1-e^2)  \times  100 \;\%$$

First of all, what does 'times 100%' mean?  Second, $e^2$ is 7.38 so is energy loss supposed to be negative?

Comment: "times 100%" just converts 0.9 to 90% by multiplying 0.9*100=90 and making % the "unit."

Comment: A loss can be considered negative, yes. Can be defined differently depending on choice. It can be useful to keep reducing components negative and adding components positive, so that you can add them all up in the end without thinking of signs.

Comment: I also think that you should not take this formula by hard. The $1-e^2$ is totally arbitrary and the more general formula would be: Energy Loss = $-factor*Current Energy$ with $factor \in [0,1]$.

Depending on your specific application it might be interesting to make "factor" partially random as it would be in real life (no two surfaces are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Actually $e$ is the coefficient of restitution and it always lies between $0$ to $1$. $e^2$ is also between $0$ to $1$, so the value cannot be $7.38$.

Percentage is the loss of energy in respect to the initial potential energy of the ball, which was at a height of $h$ initially. As the ball bounces, the height decreases $e^2$ times. And we know that gravitational potential energy is $mgh$, which means that the ball's energy will also decrease by a factor of $e^2$.

Comment: Hi @Ashish. I've added some slight math formatting to make your answer a bit nicer to look at. You can use the \$...\$ and \$\$...\$\$ symbols to do this. I hope everything is still as intended after my edit, else you can correct it.

Comment: Thank you steeven. Actually I am new to stackexchange so wasnt aware with the format and the use.